# Get module path not root path in Java

Tags: java, spring, gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

I have a multi-module Java(Spring) project, which build by Gradle 6.7.1. And I use in Jetbrain IDEA to develop. The file Structure like this:

```
root
  |--orm
  |   +---hibernates
  |
  |--web
      |--mvc
      |--rest
```

And then, I have tried some codes in my module project like below, what I get all are root path (`/home/user/IdeaProjects/root/`), not module path (`/home/user/IdeaProjects/root/web/mvc`). How can I get module path (`/home/user/IdeaProjects/root/web/mvc`) ?

```
new File("").getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: so if i understand correctly you want to get `orm...` or `web....` and not the `Root...`

Comment: @Aristotle Yes, I want to get path contain `orm` or others.

Comment: Maybe this will help `File(".").listFiles(File::isDirectory)`. You will get a list of all directories on your current project and then manage them as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming for instance that your mvc project is setup like this in `setting.gradle`, in the root folder :

```
include 'mvc'
project(':mvc').projectDir = new File('./web/mvc')
```

Then, to get the path `/home/user/IdeaProjects/root/web/mvc`, just try this :

```
println project(':mvc').projectDir
```

Will prints :

> /home/user/IdeaProjects/root/web/mvc

Answer (score 0):

based on the answer of @ToYonos. We can do that by this:

1. `settings.gradle` gets the project path of every module.
2. write a key value into the `info.properties` in every module.
3. Spring Project read this properties file.

### Code

```
Because struct of my project is:
root
  |--orm
  |   +---mybatis
  |   +---jpa
  |   +---...
  |--web
      +--mvc
      +--rest
      +--...
```

So, I should loop twice to get the module name. And I exclude project without `build.gradle`.

```
file("${rootDir}").eachDir {
    it.eachDirMatch(~/.*/) {
        if (it.list().contains("build.gradle")) {
            def moduleName = "${it.parentFile.name}:${it.name}"
            println "   ${moduleName}"
            include moduleName
}}}
```

And then, read and write `info.properties`.

```
import java.nio.file.Paths

// read
def project_dir = project(":${moduleName}").projectDir
def propFile = Paths.get("${project_dir}", "src", "main","resources","info.properties").toFile()
propFile.createNewFile()
Properties props = new Properties()
propFile.withInputStream {
    props.load(it)
}

// write
props.setProperty("project.dir","$project_dir")
props.store propFile.newWriter(), null
```